# Wrapper for converting Winapi and MFC code to equivalent linux versions

Tags: linux, mfc, wxwidgets

I'm working on a wrapper to compile c++ code having MFC and windows API calls into their linux versions.

The c++ code has the following characteristics:

- No GUI component present.
- Has a maximum of about 10 MFC classes used mostly for string parsing.
- It has lots of windows specific constants used such as HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR and so on.

I'm not allowed to compile using wine in linux. Till now i've come across wxwidgets, it seems quite vast, i doubt if i'll be needing all it's components.

Please share your ideas in creating the wrapper, is there any specific code that is already available which does this task or part of this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic or even semi-automatic way to convert an MFC application to wxWidgets. It is, of course, perfectly possible to do it and many, many projects have gone through this transformation but you just need to do it.

See [MFC page of wxWiki](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_For_MFC_Programmers) for some starting points.